# Two Grassman manifold problems from Milnor and Stasheff's book

Tags: differential-topology, characteristic-classes

I'm stuck on the following two problems in Milnor and Stasheff's book *Characteristic Classes*. Really can't get my head around this material and I'm hoping that more worked examples would help. Even some hints would be much appreciated.

**5-B:** Show that the tangent bundle of $G_n(\mathbb{R}^{n+k})$ is isomorphic to $\textrm{Hom}(\gamma^n(\mathbb{R}^{n+k}),\gamma^\perp)$, where $\gamma^\perp$ denotes the orthogonal complement of $\gamma^n(\mathbb{R}^{n+k})$ in $\varepsilon^{n+k}$. Now consider a smooth manifold $M \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+k}$. If $\bar{g}: M \to G_n(\mathbb{R}^{n+k})$ denotes the generalized Gauss map, show that $D\bar{g}: DM \to DG_n(\mathbb{R}^{n+k})$ gives rise to a cross-section of the bundle $\textrm{Hom}(r_M,\mathrm{Hom}(r_M,\nu)) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(r_M \oplus r_M, \nu)$.

**5_D:** Show that $G_n(\mathbb{R}^{n+k})$ has the following symmetry property. Given any two $n$-planes $X, Y \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ there exists an orthogonal automorphism $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ which interchanges $X$ qand $Y$. Define the angle $\alpha(X,Y)$ between  $n$-planes as the maximum over all unit vectors $x \in X$ of the angle between $x$ and $Y$. Show that $\alpha$ is a metric for the topological space $G_n(\mathbb{R}^{n+k})$ and show that $\alpha(X,Y)=\alpha(Y^\perp, X^\perp)$.

Comment: For $5-B$, the proof that every point of the Grassmanian has a neighbhorhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{nk}$ can be adapted to show the tangent space at a plane $V$ in the Grassmanian can be identified with linear maps from $V$ to $V^\bot$.  Once you have this, the identification of the bundles happens as it did for $\mathbb{R}P^n$ in chapter 4, page 44 and 45.

Comment: Exercise 5D has already been discussed on this site and is has complete, detailed answers: [MSE/830277](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/830277).